# OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost"

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to send data from a df to an PostgreSQL in Python, and keep getting this error:

**OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "mysql+pymysql"**

I was not able to find any direct solutions. I've tried deleting PostgreSQL and PgAdmin, and redownloading separately.

I believe I have the conf. is setup correctly, but am somewhat new to doing that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You will need to provide the connection setup you are using in the code as update to your question.  The fact the error contains `mysql+pymysql` is an indication you are starting down the wrong path to begin with if you are indeed trying to connect to Postgres.